# Repairing corrupted VMWare Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-server

I've got a Virtual Machine that got corrupted due to power failure. I couldn't re-attach it to the VMWare Server 2.0.2. Trying to do so is causing VMWare Host Agent to crash and the service is getting stopped.

Can anyone help how I can make the VM up & running again? Is there any too which can check the VM files & repair them?

Comment: Restore from backup.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do have a backup which is few months old. Now when I tried attaching it, it does boots up, but is not allowing me to login - it says domain not reachable, where as it does exists and my account exists on domain. But ideally my requirement is to get my VM work as it has couple of week's uncommitted code! Any such possibility?

Answer (score 2):

Server 2.0.2 sounds ancient to me, and hostd problems seem very common from a quick google... I would try setting up a small (workbench not production) ESXi 5 system on whatever usable hardware is at hand (modern PC should do, you might need to find a supported NIC) and importing the VM on that. You also have a current vmkfstools at your disposal this way...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did tried to get an environment to have ESXi 5, but unfortunately was not possible for us at the moment. I've to try hard doing something with whatever exists!!

Comment: A few months of development work usually will be more loss than buying a $200 PC, a $250 RAID card (which you can reuse for production stuff later) and $30 NIC? (edit: could do without the RAID and go the AHCI route as others have done and documented. Just dont allow anyone to promote that to permanent temporary production!)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, finally I've to use VMWare disk mount tools to accomplish data backup & restored the same on new VM. Though this didn't resolved my actual problem of repairing VM, I could get all my work back, without loss.